# How to input arabic vowels in sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, arabic, sublime-text-plugin

After using [BIDI Plugin](https://github.com/praveenvijayan/Sublime-Text-2-BIDI), my ST3 seems to support bidirectional text. But arabic vowels like َ  ً  ُ  ٌ  etc. cannot show properly when with consonants:

[please click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqQr7.png)

How can I do to make ST3 show arabic scripts properly like in notepad?

Answer (score 0):

Use this link here
Follow the instructions to install

Install the plugin and you are good to go.

[Package for bidirectional text support](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Bidirectional%20text%20support/)

Make sure you have done the installation properly.

```
 Copy the plugin folder to the following path 
 C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\

 Copy unicodedata.pyd from ST installation directory to both,
 the main plugin folder which in your case is Sublime-Text-3- 
 BIDI-master and inside bidi folder.

 Set your sublime user-settings to the following:

{
 "font-face": "arial",
  "font_size": 11,
  "default_encoding": "UTF-8",
  "fallback_encoding": "Arabic (Windows 1256)"
}
```

Reload the plugin by viewing rtl.py and saving

Comment: I've used this plugin and it supports **consonants** scripts well as shown in posted image. My question is about display of vowels, ْ and ّ  when they are with constants. Could you give some advice?

Comment: did you find the solution yet?

Comment: Haven't yet. I'll turn to other editors in such condition.

Comment: didn't solve it yet also. tried all solutions mentioned. seriously thinking of turning to other editor. Please help if you can.